# initFileURLWithPath:(NSString)] returns null

Tags: cocoa

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Opening" ofType:@"wav"];     
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
NSLog(@"@ajay");         
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer =
        [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

[fileURL release];
[audioPlayer play];
```

i have inserted a wav file in my project.But

```
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
```

returns NULL and console prints following:

and application KILLS...
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
NSLog(@"soundFilePath: %@", soundFilePath);
```

After:

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Opening" ofType:@"wav"];
```

What is printed out? If it is "null" then you do not have a file named "Opening.wav" in your bundle's Resource directory.

Make sure that you add that file to your project, **and** it appears in a "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase in your executable's target in Xcode.